# Get slices of arrays inside series

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe of lawsuits, where one of the columns is the lawsuit number, and I wanted to filter values based on the number, as it can identify if it comes from a consumer or an employee. The usual format for this number is: `0000000-11.2222.3.44.5555` which comprises 25 characters, and so initial filtering was done based on that:

```
df = df[df['lawsuit'].map(str).map(len)==25].reset_index(drop=True)
```

For some lawsuits that come from other sources may have different lenghts. The problem is that I need to filter further based on the single digit of the format above, which can indicate the nature of the lawsuit. What I have tried and it works is the following:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['check'] = df['Processo'].str.split('.')[i][-3]
```

Notice that the desired check number will always be the third from last when separated by dots, hence the index `[-3]`, and then I can select from the `check` column only the rows that fit my requirements.
The problem with that is it is costly, as my frame has more than 4 thousand rows and it gets bigger by the day. I tried the classic filtering method:

```
df[df['lawsuit'].str.split('.')[:][-3]=='8']
```

But it returns a key error. Apparently, it does not iterate over rows, taking slices from the array inside the series and checking for the condition. I am afraid I still lack the understanding of how pandas treats this kind of object.
The following is a sample input and sample output, filtering out the lawsuits that have 4 as the third from last separated by dots:

```
         lawsuit                          lawsuit
0000000-11.2222.3.44.5555        0000000-11.2222.3.44.5555
0000001-11.2222.4.44.5555        0000001-11.2222.3.44.5555
0000001-11.2222.3.44.5555        0000002-11.2222.3.44.5555
0000002-11.2222.4.44.5555        0000003-11.2222.3.44.5555
0000002-11.2222.3.44.5555        0000004-11.2222.3.44.5555
             .                                .
             .                                .
             .                                .
```

Comment: Can you post some sample or mock data with expected results?

Comment: Sample input and output edited in the question. Keep in my that the dataframe also has other columns.

Comment: `df['lawsuit'].str.split('.').str[-3]` in your test data here would return the 3 and 4 from your first column 'lawsuits'  Is this your desired value?

Comment: Yes it does, I knew it had to be simple. Can you explain the logic behind this solution?

Comment: See solution below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .str accessor to access values in a list after `split`:

```
df['lawsuit'].str.split('.').str[-3]
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    4
4    3
Name: lawsuit, dtype: object
```

In this case, get the third value from the end of the list created by `split`.
Equal to using `df['lawsuit'].str.split('.').str.get(-3)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings